# Images not display both frontend and backend after import

Tags: magento-1.9, error, import, image

I have try to import bulk images, after i import i got successful message, right after check front and back end there is no image,

excel format :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruh3bg6htuirybp/ready.csv?dl=0

Comment: Don't Suggest Magmi,

Comment: Where are the images you're importing located on your server?

Comment: media/import...

Comment: what is my error

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis : any other idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Flush Image Cache? or try the below solution

Open up the following file:

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Find this line :

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0640);
```

Replace it with this line:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0777);
```

Comment: backend : http://i.imgur.com/6aN2Cpd.png

Comment: @ Knowband : not working, am followed ur all suggestions

Comment: Is any other possibilities ??

Comment: got the positive response

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/N1w4WOb.png

Comment: After clear cache  and reindex, there is no images @ backend and frontend

Answer (score 0):

System - Import/Export - Dataflow profile - export all product - Run Profile in Popup

into to FTP /var/export/ Dowload the file ccv.

Open the file check the column STATUS this field is "enable"

SAVE File and import all product Import/Export and ready